# CSS ::before and ::after animation to center of button, but only ::after ends up in center

Tags: css, animation, transition

I've been trying to recreate the buttons 'Buy Intense now' and 'Start a journey' from this template: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/58888.html

With a little help from people around here, I came up with a solution that's almost the same, but not quite yet. I've used ::before and ::after, but the ::before event does not end in the middle of the button. That's because it's placed further away of the button (apparently), but I don't understand why.

Please see the fiddle below for more clearance.

This is what I already have:

```
<section id="button-container" class="section">
    <div id="effect" class="button">
        <span class="text">Free offer</span>
    </div>
</section>

*, *::before, *::after{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box
}
.section{
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-display:flex
}
.button{
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:200px;
    padding:20px 0px;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:relative
}
.button .text{
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-transform:uppercase
}
#button-container #effect{
    background-color:#ff7900;
    overflow:hidden
}
#button-container #effect .text{
    color:#fff;
    transition:all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s linear
}
#button-container #effect::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    transition:left .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:left .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    left:-50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#79ccf2
}
#button-container #effect::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    transition:right .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:right .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    right:-50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#79ccf2
}
#button-container #effect:hover .text{
    color:#fff;
    transition:color .5s linear .5s;
    -webkit-transition:color .5s linear .5s
}
#button-container #effect:hover::before{
     transition:left .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
     -webkit-transition:left .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
      left:50%;
      width:400px;
      height:400px
}
#button-container #effect:hover::after{
      transition:right .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
      -webkit-transition:right .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
      right:50%;
      width:400px;
      height:400px
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpcfuwoh/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `:after`'s problem.

You use position `right` to align it.

When the animation is going to animate the width of `:after`, it'll grow to the left hand side because the `right: 50%` restrict it.(You can see the slow motion below)

[image]

Change you code like this:

```
#button-container #effect::after{
    left: 150%;
    transition: left .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
}


#button-container #effect:hover::after{
    left: 50%;
    transition: left .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpcfuwoh/1/

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**
A few adjustments to the `transform` values for the alternating element states.

```
#button-container #effect:hover::before {
    transition: left .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
}

#button-container #effect::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    transition: left .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    left: -50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #79ccf2;
}

#button-container #effect:hover::after {
    transition: right .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    -webkit-transition: right .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    right: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
}

#button-container #effect::after {
content: '';
    position: absolute;
    transition: right .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: right .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    right: -50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #79ccf2;
}
```

**Snippet**
Run the snippet below to see it in action.

```css
*, *::before, *::after{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box}
.section{font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;display:flex;-webkit-display:flex}
.button{text-align:center;box-sizing:border-box;border:none;cursor:pointer;width:200px;padding:20px 0px;border-radius:5px;position:relative}
.button .text{position:relative;z-index:100;font-size:17px;font-weight:700;text-transform:uppercase}
#button-container #effect{background-color:#ff7900;overflow:hidden}
#button-container #effect .text{color:#fff;transition:all .3s linear;-webkit-transition:all .3s linear}
#button-container #effect:hover::before {
    transition: left .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
}

#button-container #effect::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    transition: left .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    left: -50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #79ccf2;
}

#button-container #effect:hover::after {
    transition: right .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    -webkit-transition: right .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
    right: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
}

#button-container #effect::after {
content: '';
    position: absolute;
    transition: right .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: right .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
    right: -50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #79ccf2;
}
```

```html
<section id="button-container" class="section">
    <div id="effect" class="button">
        <span class="text">Free offer</span>
    </div>
</section>
```